# How long would it take for Earth to become desolate after being slung from orbit?

Tags: astrophysics, earth, estimation, solar-system

I rather enjoy watching some of the what if scenarios on YouTube, and today I had one trigger my urge to seek out some knowledge on a curiosity I have.

A lot of media out there explains that the Earth orbits the sun on the inner rim of the habitable zone in our solar system and is obviously bustling with life. Mars orbits just beyond the outer rim of the habitable zone and is cold and desolate.

While listening to podcasts, reading papers, and watching videos I often hear of things that could sling Earth out of its current orbit and away into the far depths of the cosmos. For example, [what if Jupiter became a star](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSQhjhoEvLs) similar to our sun, or if a black hole entered our solar system.

I would assume that being flung out of orbit would cause our rate of travel to increase, but assuming that it remained a constant $66,000$ miles per hour, I can take an educated guess that we would reach the outer edge of the habitable zone in roughly $21$ days. I calculated this based on the rate of travel and the distance between Mars and Earth.

$$t = \frac{d}{s}$$

Where $t$ is the time it would take, $d$ is the distance between Earth and Mars, and $s$ is the speed at which Earth orbits the sun.

However, I know there are plenty more factors that would play a role in how long it would take for all life on Earth to feel the impact. That's exactly what brings me here.

---

How long would it take for life on Earth to feel the impacts of such an event?

How long would it take for Earth to become cold and desolate like Mars?

You can assume that the trajectory we get put on will ensure we don't collide with other planets or stars for millions of years.

Comment: Re, "...Jupiter became a star." You mean, if it just suddenly lit up for some reason? Not because of any new mass being added to it? That would not change the _orbit_ of the Earth or, of Jupiter or, of any other object in the Solar system. The new source of light and heat might have some _other_ effects, but it wouldn't change the motion of any astronomical bodies.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The video spoke on a point of Jupiter becoming the size of our current star, which would be 1,000 times larger than its current size if I remember correctly. This would indeed impact the orbit of all bodies in our solar system.

Comment: Earth's a fragile planet. You can't just fling it around the place by the gravity of some rogue body. That's liable to cause a major disturbance to the air and water, maybe even the crust. And if you only do 1 gravitational adjustment it will just make the orbit more eccentric, the new orbit will still pass through the point on the old orbit where the disruption occured (more or less).

Comment: Anywhere from roughly 3-8 minutes traveling roughly at the speed of light  to roughly 5 billion years - depending on the relative positions of Jupiter, Sun and Earth - and the event.

Comment: [If The Sun Went Out "Within a week, the average global surface temperature would drop below 0°F. In a year, it would dip to –100°. The top layers of the oceans would freeze over, but in an apocalyptic irony, that ice would insulate the deep water below and prevent the oceans from freezing solid for hundreds of thousands of years. Millions of years after that, our planet would reach a stable –400°, the temperature at which the heat radiating from the planet's core would equal the heat that the Earth radiates into space"](https://www.popsci.com/node/204957).

Comment: @PerpetualJ, it would be helpful if you were more specific.  One question you asked was: "How long would it take for life on Earth to feel the impacts of such an event?".  Humans would feel the effects immediately.  Creatures living off of the heat and emissions from undersea volcanic vents may not ever feel the effects.